# Why have the cold fusion prototypes not been more closely considered as instances of muon catalyzed fusion

Tags: cold-fusion

We have some evidence of excess heat being generated by Pons & Fleischmann type experiments. Ultimately, I want to understand why the orthodoxy put down the muon theory & shut down the entire line of inquiry. Is Eric Weinstein right? Have physicists become corrupt? Or were Pons & Fleischmann just frauds?

#geometric-unity?

Comment: What’s the muon theory? Where would the muons have come from? Cosmic rays?

Comment: What is the relationship between cold fusion and Eric Weinstein’s “Geometric Unity”?

Comment: *Have physicists become corrupt?* Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence. You present NONE. *Or were Pons & Fleischmann just frauds?* More likely incompetents bungling things up, IMHO. Occam's razor.

Comment: The intent of this question was to spur debate regarding any heterodox idea within an orthodox community. I like the continuous muon source response.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need a continuous muon source even to test this hypothesis, and none of the cold fusion cells had muon sources.